# What's the difference between 塀 and 垣

Tags: word-choice

Is there a difference in usage depending on the situation?

Comment: 画像検索してみたら・・・・・・

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple image search would answer the question.

Comment: Does this link help you? https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A1%80

Answer (score 1):

塀: a fence made of/from wooden board, clay, or concrete

垣: a hedge made of shrubs, trees, or bamboos